# Detect if user's phone ringed for outbound call in freeswitch javascript

Tags: javascript, freeswitch

I'm using javascript in Freeswitch. I'm finding the way to detect user's phone ringed for outbound call. Any chance to detect if session is ringing or detect callstate change from `DOWN->RINGING` ? . I've read freeswitch javascript document but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have your outbound call logic, here's the implementation

```
const session = freeswitch.Session("<your_outbound_number>");
session.addEventListener('CHANNEL_STATE', onChannelStateChange);

function onChannelStateChange(event) {
  const { unique_id, channel_state, channel_state_desc } = event.getHeader();

  if (channel_state_desc === 'RINGING' && channel_state === '4') {
    console.log('Call is ringing.');
    // Your logic here to handle the ringing state
  }
}
```

Comment: `session` not having `addEventListener` method.